# how css style inheritence works

Tags: css, inheritance, menu

I'm new to css and want to have a simple and clear understand about the css style inheritance. Thanks for help.
The following is a horizontal navigation bar I'm trying to create.
First I did this to reset the global padding and margin (I read some tutorial and believe this is a good practice.

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Then I added some padding to my li to add some gap between menu items.

```
.navi ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-right: 1px dashed #770;
    position: relative;
}
```

The following is a sub-menu item. I noticed that a padding-left of 10px was added automatically, which I think I need to add manually.

```
.navi ul li ul li {
    border-right: none;
    border-top: 1px dashed #789;
    width: 200px;
}
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $app_name ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="page_title">
                    <?php
                        echo "<h1>$app_name</h1>";
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="navi">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Menu1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="contents">
</div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: show the html please?

Comment: @leon : so what is the question here?

Comment: Why my sub-menu get padding? I have removed all padding at the beginning.

Comment: @leon css has priority based . if you give padding for parent conatiner, again you give some padding for child container it overides the parent conatiner style.

Comment: while using `*` selector you remove the by default `padding` and `margin` for the HTML element. And later on you are again define the padding and margin. As you gave the padding for first `li` and its treated as parent element; this is the reason `padding` applied to child level `li`.

Comment: _Off topic_: [This](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade) is a good documentation if someone needs to find out how inheritance in CSS works (since that is the topic of the question, and someone could come here while searching for _that_ document).

Comment: @leon I hope now you understand why padding working on second level `li`.

Comment: @Kheema Pandey, thanks for your answer. One more question here. In my example, if I added padding to the first level ul instead of li, will it affects my second level li? I means does the inheritance target  children of same tag or just apply to any children.

Comment: The text of the question has nothing to do with inheritance – and there is really no question presented there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a some Explanation. Build a **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nuxowero/1/edit)** also.

```
 /*Will remove margin and padding from all the HTML element used in page As you are using `*` Universal Selector*/
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*only affect the first level  li*/
.navi ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 10px; /*As the padding given to parent `li` so the padding applied to second level `li` as well */
    border-right: 1px dashed #770;
    position: relative;
  color:green;
}

/*only affect the Second Level  li*/
.navi ul li ul li {
    border-right: none;
    border-top: 1px dashed #789;
    width: 200px;
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Which question does this answer?

Answer (score 0):

By writing

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

you are removing margin and padding from all the elements.

Following code

```
.navi ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-right: 1px dashed #770;
    position: relative;
}
```

adds styling to all the `li`s that have parent `ul`, which has parent `.navi`.

Please note, this includes all the `li`s, irrespective of the level, means it could be `.navi ul li`, or `.navi ul li ul li`, or `.navi ul li ul li ul li` and so on.

Following code

```
.navi ul li ul li {
    border-right: none;
    border-top: 1px dashed #789;
    width: 200px;
}
```

adds styling to `.navi ul li ul li` or `.navi ul li ul li ul li` and so on.

Probable solution of what you are asking:

Change

`.navi ul li`

to

`.navi > ul > li`

This will style only direct children of `ul` of `.navi`. i.e first level `li`s.

And,

Change

`.navi ul li ul li`

to

`.navi li > ul > li`

This code will affect to only direct `li`s of `ul` of `li`s in `.navi`. i.e. second level of `li`s.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz8dz/1) here.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navi ul li {
float: left;
padding: 0px 10px;
border-right: 1px dashed #770;
position: relative;
}
```

The above class will apply all the `li` tag under the `navi` class div. When you use `space` between your selector means it will target all the child selectors. Suppose If you want to target only first level child then you need to use `>` between your selector like below.

```
.navi > ul > li {
float: left;
padding: 0px 10px;
border-right: 1px dashed #770;
position: relative;
}
```

So the above code will find first level child of `UL` from `.navi`, from that it will check first level child of `LI`. If you declare like above in your CSS, then you need to explicitly mentioned the padding for second level child as you expected.

[Read for Better Understanding of Child Selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html)